# Black screen when emulating Linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, qemu

I'am trying to build linux for an arm (versatile board) and emulate it using Qemu:

I folowed the folowing [tutorial](http://www.kaizou.org/2016/09/boot-minimal-linux-qemu/)

After downloading Qemu and the arm-linux-gnueab toolchain the steps are basically:

- `make -C build ARCH=arm distclean`
- `make -C build ARCH=arm versatile_defconfig`
- `make -C build ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-`
- `qemu-system-arm -M versatileab -m 256M -kernel build/arch/arm/boot/zImage -append "console=ttyS0" -serial stdio -dtb build/arch/arm/boot/dts/versatile-ab.dtb`

What I get is black sreen with a cursor at the top and the following messages:

```
pulseaudio: set_sink_input_volume() failed
pulseaudio: Reason: Invalid argument
pulseaudio: set_sink_input_mute() failed
pulseaudio: Reason: Invalid argument
Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
vpb_sic_write: Bad register offset 0x2c
```

I'am not sure from where the problem come from: is it from the bad configuration of the kernel ?, the dtb ?; the messages don't really give a lot of informations

So your suggestions are welcome

Qemu version:

```
qemu-system-arm --version
QEMU emulator version 2.0.0 (Debian 2.0.0+dfsg-2ubuntu1.31), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

My machine:

```
uname -a
Linux user-SATELLITE-C855-169 4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 15:32:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The device `ttyS0` is usually for PC-style 8250/16550 serial ports, whereas QEMU emulates an AMBA PL011 for the versatibleab and versatilepb machines, which use the device name `ttyAMA0`, so you can try using `console=ttyAMA0` instead.

The framebuffer console may need binding by the kernel during startup, which is controlled by setting `FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE_DETECT_PRIMARY=y` in the kernel config, that should allow a console on the `tty0` device using `console=tty0`.

You can specify multiple `console=` options so using `console=ttyAMA0 console=tty0` should show the kernel boot messages on both the emulated console port (on stdio, with your options) and the framebuffer.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, i don't have the laptop now but i will try it and get back to you. just a question : how we can know the available devices names before starting the kernel ?

Comment: that works, thank you, could you please give more details about how can one choose the good `tty` device ?

Comment: The framebuffer is always bound to tty/tty0 if it is enabled.  For serial consoles you can check the DTS file.  In `arch/arm/boot/dts/versatile-pb.dts` search for `uart`, and you will find the driver name `pl011`. Search for that filename and you find `drivers/tty/serial/amba-pl011.c`.  In that file search for `struct uart_driver` and you find a structure with `.dev_name = "ttyAMA"` - that is the name you should use (with the device index number appended).